# Some javascript assets getting 404 spring 5

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I'm upgrading from spring 3 to spring 5. 
I'm having some problems with some of my javascripts file getting 404 when loading. I can't see why some will load and some won't

my spring resources are defined as such

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/assets" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/css" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/js" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/**" location="/third-party" />
```

I'm using a jsp MVC. the path of the page being loaded is http://localhost:8080/myroot/login.jsp

In login.jsp I have there javascript files linked

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="assets/js/google-code-prettify/prettify.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="third-party/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
```

The everything in 'assets' loads but the last one in 'third-party' gets a 404.

The file does exist. If I revert back to spring 3 it all works again.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as usual once I post a question I figure out the issue..
So, it seems that I needed to define my resources differently.

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/third-party/**" location="/third-party/" />
```

This worked.. Defining them in the previous way I was able to have assets in different locations without having to define them all.. For example /assets and /gui/assets the original

worked.. but now with spring 5 I need to do

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/gui/**" location="/gui/" />
```

Then the path to the resource /myroot/gui/assets/my.js with be found